# Efficient string replace in a stream

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I need to replace a string in a streaming http response. The naive way of doing that would be

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(input, leaveOpen: true);
var original = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
var replaced = original.Replace(old, new, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
await output.WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(replaced));
```

This is very resource and memory intensive since the complete response must be read into memory before replacing the strings.

I've been looking at `System.IO.Pipelines` and the `PipeReader`. While this does give me efficient access to the stream, it works on `byte` which makes the conversion to char problematic when working in Utf-8.

One method I've seen is to use `ReadLineAsync` on the streamreader, but I cannot know if the stream will contain any newlines.

Another method I've seen is to use a queue, but even that seems clumsy.

So my question is: what is the best way to replace text is a stream without reading the full stream in memory?

Comment: why not read it through buffer eg. this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.read?view=net-8.0#system-io-streamreader-read(system-span((system-char))) the returned int signals how many chars have been read

Comment: Consider that you need a buffer that is perhaps 2x the length of the string you seek, you fill it, then seek, emit half the buffer, slide the latter half over the former and append to the latter half of the buffer, seek again.. This way you're taking a sliding window through the data that, at some point, will be large enough to contain the string you seek, and will contain it if it is to be found.. You can tune the buffer size. Another naive implementation would be to read and emit 1 char at a time and as soon as a char is the same as the start of the string you seek, buffer the length & check

Comment: (But be careful to drop back to single char mode soon; if you're reading single char looking for "hello" in a stream of "wellhellhellothere", as soon as you find the first h, buffer 5 bytes and check if they're "hello" but don't output all 5 in one go if they aren't because you'll miss the true hello if you output its h as part of the 5)

Comment: It's the sliding part that I have problems with. Do you just copy over char by char to the correct positions?

Comment: What is the point in "replacing" when you don't read the complete HTTP response? You read the response, find the token and replace it. Do you mean "replace" or "find"? Both make a big difference.

Comment: @BionicCode I need to read the complete response in order to replace some text, but it is not very efficient to hold the complete response in memory in order to do that. This is in the critical path of the application so I need it to be efficient.

Comment: I will post a solution later. I don't expect that there are any significant performance improvements when replacing tokens on the fly opposed to replacing them when the result is complete. You don't want to mess with the size of the blocks you read from the Stream. Your idea makes sense for infinite streams like socket streams. But for finite streams I don't expect any benefits.

Comment: I agree with @BionicCode. Is the response particularly huge such that you just can't afford to keep it in memory in an intermediate step before writing it to `output`? Otherwise any performance improvement would be practically imperceivable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an infinite `Stream` like a `NetworkStream`, replacing string tokens on-the-fly would make a lot of sense. But because you are processing a finite stream of which you need the *complete* content, such a filtering doesn't make sense because of the performance impact.

My argument is that you would have to use buffering. The size of the buffer is of course restricting the amount of characters you can process. Assuming you use a ring buffer or kind of a queue, you would have to remove one character to append a new. This leads to a lot of drawbacks when compared to processing the complete content.

Pros & Cons

| Full-content search & replace | Buffered (real-time) search & replace |
| --- | --- |
| Single pass over the full range | multiple passes over the same range |
| Advanced search (e.g. backtracking, look-ahead etc.) | Because characters get dropped at the start of the buffer, the search engine loses context |
| Because we have the full context available, we won't ever miss a match | Because characters get dropped at the start of the buffer, there will be edge cases where the searched token does not fit into the buffer. Of course, we can resize the buffer to a length = n * token_length. However, this limitation impacts performance as the optimal buffer size is now constrained by the token size. The worst case is that the token length equals the length of the stream. Based on the search algorithm we would have to keep input in the buffer until we match all key words and then discard the matched part. If there is no match the buffer size would equal the size of the stream. In streaming scenarios e.g. network socket, we don't even know the stream size in advance (expect it to be infinite). In this case we have to define a "random" buffer size and risk to lose matches that span across multiple buffer reads. It makes sense to evaluate the expected input and search keys for the worst-case scenarios and switch to a full-context search to get rid of the buffer management overhead. Just to highlight that the efficiency of a real-time search is very much limited by the input and the search keys (expected scenario). It can't be faster than full-context search. It potentially consumes less memory under optimal circumstances. |
| Don't have to worry about an optimal buffer size to maximize efficiency | Buffer size becomes more and more important the longer the source content is. Too small buffers result in too many buffer shifts and too many passes over the same range. Note, the key cost for the original search & replace task is the string search and the replace/modification, so it makes sense to reduce the number of comparisons to an absolute minimum. |
| Consumes more memory. However, this is not relevant in this case as we will store the complete response in (client) memory anyways. And if we use the appropriate text search technique, we avoid all the extra `string` allocations that occur during the search & replace. | Only the size of the buffers are allocated. However, this is not relevant in this case as we will store the complete response in (client) memory anyways. |
| Does not allow to filter the stream in real-time (not relevant in this case)). However, a hybrid solution is possible where we would filter certain parts in real-time (e.g. a preamble) | Allows to filter the stream in real-time so that we can make decisions based on content e.g. abort the reading (not relevant in this case). |

I stop here as the most relevant performance costs search & replace are better for the full-content solution. For the real-time search & replace we basically would have to implement our own algorithm that has to compete against the .NET search and replace algorithms. No problem, but considering the effort and the final use case I would not waste any time on that.

An efficient solution could implement a custom `TextReader`, an advanced `StreamReader` that operates on a `StringBuilder` to search and replace characters. While `StringBuilder` offers a significant performance advantage over the string search & replace it does not allow complex search patterns like word boundaries. For example, word boundaries are only possible if the patter explicitly includes the bounding characters.

For example, replacing "int" in the input "internal int " with "pat" produces "paternal pat". If we want to replace only "int" in "internal int " we would have to use regular expression. Because regular expression only operates on `string` we have to pay with efficiency.

The following example implements a `StringReplaceStreamReader` that extends `TextReader` to act as a specialized `StreamReader`. For best performance, tokens are replaced *after* the complete stream has been read.
For brevity it only supports `ReadToEndAsync`, `Read` and `Peak` methods.
It supports simple search where the search pattern is simply matched against the input (called simple-search).
Then it also supports two variants of regular expression search and replace for more advanced search and replace scenarios.
The first variant is based on a set of key-value pairs while the second variant uses a regex pattern provided by the caller.

Because simple-search involves iteration of the source dictionary entries + multiple passes (one for each entry) this search mode is expected to be the slowest algorithm, although the replace using a `StringBuilder` itself is actually faster. Under these circumstances, the `Regex` search & replace is expected to be significantly faster than the simple search and replace using the `StringBuilder` as it can process the input in a single pass.

The `StringReplaceStreamReader` search behavior is configurable via constructor.

### Usage example

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> replacementTable;

private async Task ReplaceInStream(Stream sourceStream)
{
  this.replacementTable = new Dictionary<string, string>
  {
    { "private", "internal" },
    { "int", "BUTTON" },
    { "Read", "Not-To-Read" }
  };

  // Search and replace using simple search 
  // (slowest).
  await using var streamReader = new StringReplaceStreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Default, this.replacementTable, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  string text = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

  // Search and replace variant #1 using regex with key-value pairs instead of a regular expression pattern
  // for advanced scenarios (fast)
  await using var streamReader2 = new StringReplaceStreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Default, this.replacementTable, SearchMode.Regex);
  string text2 = await streamReader2.ReadToEndAsync();

  // Search and replace variant #2 using regex and regular expression pattern 
  // for advanced scenarios (fast).
  // The matchEvaluator callback actually provides the replcement value for each match.

  // Creates the following regular expression:
  // "\bprivate\b|\bint\b|\bRead\b"
  string searchPattern = this.replacementTable.Keys
    .Select(key => $@"\b{key}\b")
    .Aggregate((current, newValue) => $"{current}|{newValue}");

  await using var streamReader3 = new StringReplaceStreamReader(sourceStream, Encoding.Default, searchPattern, Replace);
  string text3 = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}


private string Replace(Match match) 
  => this.replacementTable.TryGetValue(match.Value, out string replacement) 
    ? replacement 
    : match.Value;
```

### Implementation

**SearchMode**

```cs
public enum SearchMode
{
  Default = 0,
  Simple,
  Regex
}
```

**StringReplaceStreamReader.cs**

```cs
public class StringReplaceStreamReader : TextReader, IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable
{
  public Stream BaseStream { get; }
  public long Length => this.BaseStream.Length;
  public bool EndOfStream => this.BaseStream.Position == this.BaseStream.Length;

  public SearchMode SearchMode { get; }

  private const int DefaultCapacity = 4096;
  private readonly IDictionary<string, string> stringReplaceTable;
  private readonly StringComparison stringComparison;
  private readonly Encoding encoding;
  private readonly Decoder decoder;
  private readonly MatchEvaluator? matchEvaluator;
  private readonly Regex? regularExpression;
  private readonly byte[] byteBuffer;
  private readonly char[] charBuffer;

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, IDictionary<string, string> stringReplaceTable)
    : this(stream, encoding, stringReplaceTable, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, SearchMode.Simple)
  {
  }

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, IDictionary<string, string> stringReplaceTable, SearchMode searchMode)
    : this(stream, encoding, stringReplaceTable, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, searchMode)
  {
  }

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, IDictionary<string, string> stringReplaceTable, StringComparison stringComparison)
    : this(stream, encoding, stringReplaceTable, stringComparison, SearchMode.Simple)
  {
  }

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, IDictionary<string, string> stringReplaceTable, StringComparison stringComparison, SearchMode searchMode)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(stream, nameof(stream));
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(stringReplaceTable, nameof(stringReplaceTable));

    this.BaseStream = stream;
    this.encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.Default;
    this.decoder = this.encoding.GetDecoder();
    this.stringReplaceTable = stringReplaceTable;
    this.stringComparison = stringComparison;
    this.SearchMode = searchMode;
    this.regularExpression = null;
    this.matchEvaluator = ReplaceMatch;

    if (searchMode is SearchMode.Regex)
    {
      RegexOptions regexOptions = CreateDefaultRegexOptions(stringComparison);

      var searchPatternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in stringReplaceTable)
      {
        // Creates the following regular expression:
        // "\b[search_key]\b|\b[search_key]\b"
        string pattern = @$"\b{entry.Key}\b";
        searchPatternBuilder.Append(pattern);
        searchPatternBuilder.Append('|');
      }

      string searchPattern = searchPatternBuilder.ToString().TrimEnd('|');
      this.regularExpression = new Regex(searchPattern, regexOptions);
    }

    this.byteBuffer = new byte[StringReplaceStreamReader.DefaultCapacity];
    int charBufferSize = this.encoding.GetMaxCharCount(this.byteBuffer.Length);
    this.charBuffer = new char[charBufferSize];
  }

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, string searchAndReplacePattern, MatchEvaluator matchEvaluator)
    : this(stream, encoding, searchAndReplacePattern, matchEvaluator, RegexOptions.None)
  {
  }

  public StringReplaceStreamReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, string searchAndReplacePattern, MatchEvaluator matchEvaluator, RegexOptions regexOptions)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(stream, nameof(stream));
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(searchAndReplacePattern, nameof(searchAndReplacePattern));
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(matchEvaluator, nameof(matchEvaluator));

    this.BaseStream = stream;
    this.encoding = encoding ?? Encoding.Default;
    this.decoder = this.encoding.GetDecoder();
    this.matchEvaluator = matchEvaluator;
    this.SearchMode = SearchMode.Regex;
    this.stringReplaceTable = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    this.stringComparison = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;

    if (regexOptions is RegexOptions.None)
    {
      regexOptions = CreateDefaultRegexOptions(stringComparison);
    }
    else if ((regexOptions & RegexOptions.Compiled) == 0)
    {
      regexOptions |= RegexOptions.Compiled;
    }

    this.regularExpression = new Regex(searchAndReplacePattern, regexOptions);
    this.byteBuffer = new byte[StringReplaceStreamReader.DefaultCapacity];
    int charBufferSize = this.encoding.GetMaxCharCount(this.byteBuffer.Length);
    this.charBuffer = new char[charBufferSize];
  }

  public override int Peek()
  {
    int value = Read();
    this.BaseStream.Seek(this.BaseStream.Position - 1, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return value;
  }

  public override int Read()
    => this.BaseStream.ReadByte();

  public override Task<string> ReadToEndAsync()
    => ReadToEndAsync(CancellationToken.None);

  public override async Task<string> ReadToEndAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    if (!this.BaseStream.CanRead)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Source stream is not readable.");
    }

    var textBuilder = new StringBuilder(StringReplaceStreamReader.DefaultCapacity);

    while (!this.EndOfStream)
    {
      cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

      int bytesRead = await this.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      bool flush = this.EndOfStream;
      int charsRead = this.decoder.GetChars(this.byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead, this.charBuffer, 0, flush);
      textBuilder.Append(charBuffer, 0, charsRead);
    }

    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    SearchAndReplace(textBuilder, cancellationToken, out string result);

    return result;
  }

  public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    => ((IAsyncDisposable)this.BaseStream).DisposeAsync();

  private void SearchAndReplace(StringBuilder textBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken, out string result)
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    if (this.SearchMode is SearchMode.Simple or SearchMode.Default)
    {
      foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in this.stringReplaceTable)
      {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        textBuilder.Replace(entry.Key, entry.Value);
      }

      result = textBuilder.ToString();
    }
    else if (this.SearchMode is SearchMode.Regex)
    {
      string input = textBuilder.ToString();
      result = this.regularExpression!.Replace(input, this.matchEvaluator!);
    }
    else
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException($"Search mode {this.SearchMode} is not implemented.");
    }
  }

  private string ReplaceMatch(Match match)
    => this.stringReplaceTable.TryGetValue(match.Value, out string replacement)
      ? replacement
      : match.Value;

  private RegexOptions CreateDefaultRegexOptions(StringComparison stringComparison)
  {
    RegexOptions regexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled;
    if (stringComparison is StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase or StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase or StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
      regexOptions |= RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
    }

    return regexOptions;
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there still a problem with UTF8 if the end of the buffer is in the middle of a multi byte character?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't handling multi-byte characters correctly. It's now fixed and improved. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Nitpick: decoder is never assigned, but I guess that this is `encoding.GetDecoder()`

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. Why don't you just use a `StreamReader` to do the decoding for you?
I also need the search to be case insensitive, so I need to use the slow regex option. I'll benchmark this and compare to what I had cooked up.

Comment: @Lodewijk Yes, indeed, I missed pasting it in. The field is now properly initialized. I wasn't using a `StreamReader` internally because I originally needed more control over the moment I finalize the byte data to create the `string`. I was also trying to provide a solution for on-the-fly search&replace. But I then changed the algorithm, dropped the on-the-fly search&replace due to the bad efficiency for your scenario.

Comment: @Lodewijk If you want to remove the feature to search&replace by a dictionary (simple search without regex) then I would extend `StreamReader` rather than wrapping it. Then override the `ReadToEndAsync` and `ReadAsync` members. Call the base implementation and process the result. But if you want to keep the feature, the `StreamReader` is not a good option as the API only returns a `string`.

Comment: @Lodewijk This is because we must use the `StringBuilder` to improve the search&replace efficiency (*replace* in particular as `string` is immutable and replacing characters of a `string` instance means that we are always creating a new instance), we can't use the `StreamReader`. Instead, we have to implement the stream processing by ourselves in order to be able to work on a `StringBuilder` exclusively. It significantly improves performance, at least in regards to memory allocation and therefore also speed.

Comment: @Lodewijk I have to review my answer if your key takeaway in regards of expected performance is that Regex is slower. I was trying to make the point that *normally* Regex would be much slower than a simple search&replace using the `StringBuilder` (for not too complex patterns), but because of the iteration of the dictionary entries and having the `StringBuilder` reparsing the input foreach entry, the Regex should be significantly faster. I would be happy if you could assert that statement I made with profiling results. The regex variant is quite fast in the end.

Comment: @BionicCode yes, I'm surprised on how fast regex.replace is. But since you need to dump the stringbuilder to string to use it, I don't think it will be necessary to us it in my case.

Comment: @Lodewijk You mean you don't want to use regex or the StringBuilder search& replace? I think in this special scenario regex is faster maybe except you want to search a single keyword. Then StringBuilder should be faster.

Comment: So, I benchmarked it. String.Replace is fastest if case sensitive, but really slows down when you use IgnoreCase. Regex.Replace is almost as fast, but allocates more memory on the heap. Streaming over a sliding buffer and replacing as you go is slower than Regex, but faster that String.Replace and memory allocation is way lower.
So I need to make a decision between memory and speed :D

Comment: @Lodewijk Interesting. Have you also tested StringBuilder.Replace? As you are working with streams you have the luxury to work on char arrays to completely avoid string allocations. StringBuilder should play an important role as it represents a highly optimized type that you have to compete with when implementing string search and replace manually. Searching in buffer depends highly on implementation details. I really doubt that this version is faster than string.Replace on the full input, as you said. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Lodewijk Regarding decision making: in my opinion both cost factors, memory and speed, are not relevant in general. Unless you are operating on a platform with small memory (e.g. microcontroller) or in a real-time data processing context, all that matters is user experience (UX). While using an application, a user never cares about memory consumption (except storage memory). But a user very much hates to wait.

Comment: @Lodewijk This makes time/speed the biggest factor in terms of performance related UX. Accumulating speed costs is therefore more significant and always more relevant since it's the 21th century where memory is cheap and plentiful. I would always pick speed over memory.

Comment: @Lodewijk The search key's complexity is also very interesting. For example, to replace all occurrences of "peace" with "harmony" but e.g. not composed words like "peaceful" then `string.Replace' becomes complicated to utilize efficiently. The design of the benchmark should cover such scenarios unless such cases are not relevant for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

My thought:

1. Read some chars from the input stream and fill a buffer.
2. Search `old[0]` in the buffer:

   - If not found, output the whole buffer, then go to step 1.
   - If found, compare the remaining chars in `old`:

     - If the complete `old` sequence is found, first output the chars before the position of `old[0]`, then output `new`. Go back to step 2.
     - If reached the end of buffer, first output the chars before the position of `old[0]`, then move the remaining chars to the start of the buffer. Go to step 1.
     - If a char doesn't match, then go back to step 2 and start from the next one.

Comment: Won't they still have a problem with UTF-8 and higher-order characters? I think they'd need to decode the UTF-8 manually while also looking for the sequence, finite state machine style.